# Trailing slash always get added in the end of a url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

In my site i have a different forum installation which is accessible through `/ubb` url. A trailing slash is always getting added so `/ubb` becomes `/ubb/`

Only rule i am using in apache configuration related to it

```
Rewriterule ^/ubb(.*)$ - [L]
```

I checked if any `.htaccess` is present inside `ubb` folder but there is none.

Possibly how this trailing slash is getting added?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your `.htaccess` file

```
DirectorySlash Off
```